# Quick Smoke not showing up or working

Tags: smoke-simulation

Whenever I try to apply quick smoke to an object it neither shows up in my object view or render. I have tried multiple times to get it to work but nothing happens. I've tried searching the answer online but no one else appears to have the same problem. I'm using 2.8 and the render engine is in Eevee.

Comment: As of 2.8, you'll have to bake it to see the actual result (*Physics Tab>Bake*). Does that help?

Comment: I'm in 2.83.5 and this still doesn't work. Even when baking. But for me it seems to be selective, i.e. it works in a totally blank (new) Blender file, but not in any established scene.